# iOS and ARC : How to retain self during asynchronous operations?

Tags: objective-c, ios, automatic-ref-counting

It's the first time I'm fiddling around with iOS5 and ARC. So far, so good, it works, but I've run into some kind of a problem.

I have a custom `UIStoryboardSegue` in which I use Facebook Connect (or other services) to log the user into my app. Simply put, it should do the following :

1. User clicks on the button
2. Button fires the Segue
3. The segue starts asynchronous login but does not immediately push the view controller
4. If, and only if the login is successful, the segue pushes the view controller

What happens instead, is that the login starts, but the segue is immediately released by ARC before it has any chance to complete.

I thought of a quick'n'dirty hack to prevent this:

```c
@interface BSLoginSegue() {
    __strong BSLoginSegue *_retained_self;
}
@end

// Stuff...
// Other stuff...

- (void) perform {
    login();
    _retained_self = self;
}

- (void) loginServiceDidSucceed:(BSLoginService *)svc {
    ...
    _retained_self = nil;
}
```

The thing is, it *really* is *a hack*, so I was wondering if there were any other, and more elegant way I could do the  same?

Comment: if you handle the case where the login fails, i wouldn't personally consider this a hack :)

Comment: @NickH247: Of course I do, the code here is voluntarily stripped of everything to make it simpler to understand ;)

Comment: @jajo87: I'm developing this for a small company, so I'll have to ask them if the NDA allows me to disclose parts of the code. If they agree, then yes, of course!

Comment: @jajo87: There you go, it's on GitHub : https://github.com/besport/BSLoginServices :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The idea that a class should need to retain itself suggests that there might be a design problem. When an object retains itself, it becomes unclear who owns it or who might have a reference to it, and the risk of a leak is high.

What class is responsible for presenting the segue? Is it the same class the contains the button? This class should retain the segue, present the segue, and then release the segue when/if the segue completes.

Without further insight into the view controller hierarchy, it's hard to give specific advice. But my first reaction is to suggest that the view controller that is deciding to present the segue or not should have a strong property on the segue. The subclassed segue might define a protocol that the presenting class may conform to to be advised as to when the segue should be nilled/released.

Comment: You just gave me an idea, I'll try implementing it, and will come back later if it works.

Comment: How did you make it a strong reference? When you say is created by UIKit, do you mean that you've created it in a Storyboard and so you are not instantiating it in code?

Comment: I did not make it a strong reference, I wanted to try, but then I thought about something else : what do you think about having my login class maintain a strong reference to its delegate (the segue) while it's active, and then setting it to nil when it's not? Also, yes, I added it inside the storyboard and did not bother further.

Comment: The last comment sounds like the right solution to me - the login class maintains a strong reference to the segue  while it is being presented (and the segue has a weak reference to the login controller because the login controller is its delegate).

Comment: Actually, I think the problem is that the Segue is being created too early, before it's needed. The Segue probably should NOT be the login service delegate at all, some other class should be this delegate and should only create the segue if and when it is needed.

Comment: Since Segues are new, I'm not exactly sure what is, or is not a good way of using them. I don't think the Segue is created too early, though. Actually, the issue seems to be the opposite : it's created when I touch a button, performs and then immediately releases.

If you have an owner retaining the segue while the request is in progress, it works. Also, note the you must take care to disable user interaction on your main view, else you can fire multiple segues simultaneously, which would be bad.

Comment: I voted you down. NSURLConnection retains itself thus this is not a design problem.

Comment: @indiekiduk Have you read Apple's documentation on memory management? What on earth are you talking about? https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmPractical.html

Comment: @indiekiduk - Objects should not retain themselves. Suggesting that they should is inviting memory leaks. There are some exceptions to this principle of memory management, but not in the scope of this question. If you want to write software that leaks, go ahead, but don't down vote answers that advocate best practices.

Answer (score 9):

If you use [Grand Central Dispatch](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Performance/Reference/GCD_libdispatch_Ref/Reference/reference.html) (GCD) for concurrency (which you should, it's awesome!) then by putting a reference to your object in an [Objective-C block](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/Blocks/Articles/00_Introduction.html) and passing it into GCD, it will be automatically retained by the block until after the block has executed and itself been released.

Without knowing exactly how you're doing your async operations it's hard to give a definitive answer, but by using [blocks](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/Blocks/Articles/00_Introduction.html) and [GCD](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Performance/Reference/GCD_libdispatch_Ref/Reference/reference.html) you won't have to worry about this at all. The block will take care of retaining objects it references and ARC will do the rest.

It looks like you must be storing a reference to your `UIStoryboardSegue` subclass somewhere, in order to call `loginServiceDidSucceed:` on it, so perhaps just making that a strong reference will work. Once again, referencing it from a [block](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/Blocks/Articles/00_Introduction.html) (such as a completion block when the login succeeds) is ideal. I would recommend adapting your login code to use blocks for the success/failure callbacks.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I'm sure it would be much more efficient with blocks, but for the sake of curiosity, is there some kind of low-level method I can use to retain/release objects in special cases such as this?

Comment: Well if you really wanted to hack it that way you could call retain and release in a way that the compiler can't detect and complain about (it's easy enough, but I'll leave that as an exercise). However, this situation is a good indication that you've structured your classes poorly (in terms of who 'owns' what in the Objective-C sense) and I highly recommend you look into that instead. :)

Answer (score 1):

Just add and remove `self` to/from an array that is a data member of `self` as follows:

```
@interface MyClass
{
    NSMutableArray* _selfRetains;
}
@end

@implementation MyClass
-(id)retainSelf
{ 
    [_selfRetains addObject:self];
    return self;
}
-(void)releaseSelf
{
    [_selfRetains removeLastObject];
}
@end
```

Then, replace `[self retain]` with `[self retainSelf]` and `[self release]` with `[self releaseSelf]`.

While the other answers are correct, and you should usually avoid a design that requires a class to retain itself, this workaround does not require you to significantly change the design of your app.

Answer (score -2):

Singleton may be your choice if you need to retain your self instance in async operation.